# Buck converter Mosfet gate driver

Tags: battery-charging, buck, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, bootstrap

How to turn on a buck transistor via a bootstrap circuit?

In my circuit, I use a AVR microcontroller to turn on and off a buck switch.  What circuit should I use here?

Previously, I used optocoupler which does not have a fast response. I like to turn on and off the transistor for no more than 500 ns on/off transition.

There are some high side low side ICs which are designed for bridges and I am not sure if they would work for here.

Solutions with BJT/Capacitor/Diodes are very pleasant to me though I dont limit myself to only those solutions.

[image: gate driver]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an N-channel MOSFET, for it to come into an "on" (low-resistance) state Vgs must be large, let's say 5V. The highest voltage you have is 36 V (+ node of battery). Even this will not fully turn-on the NMOS. You would need at least 41 V on the gate.
Instead I would use a PMOS, then you can just pull the gate low.
But to switch it OFF the gate of the PMOS must be pulled to 36 V !
An AVR cannot handle this so you would need an additional transistor to pull the gate of the PMOS down.

A 1n4001 is not fast enough for these type of applications, better use a Schottky diode.

There is a fundamental flaw in your circuit! It has no current limiting !
This is an issue, especially when the battery pack has a low voltage and the inductor saturates. The current would only be limited by the series resistance of the batteries and this is BAD, avoid at all cost ! (Your wires could melt !)

Have a look at [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva559/snva559.pdf) document form TI and learn how it's done !

If you want to actually build this then I strongly advise you to use an IC for that but pay attention to the 36V battery voltage, not all ICs can handle that.
Also there are a lot of ready-built modules for sale on eBay, that would be more convenient as the layout of a switched converter is not something for a beginner.

In general, you don't want an AVR or any micro Controller to control a DC-DC converter switch. They're too slow, software could get stuck with the switch turned on. The current will be uncontrolled. AVOID !!!

I do not understand what you mean by "designed for bridges" ?

Comment: “_designed for bridges_” -I think he means full bridge/half bridge MOSFET drivers.

Comment: @Dzarda yes, I mean haf/full bridge

Comment: OK, I see. Bridge in the context of motor drivers. That would be highly unusual and not solve any of the other pitfalls.

Comment: I use PWM mode of microcontroller which is independent from code and is controlled by my microcontroller block. Though my circuit has not resistor to limit, it has an inductor which limits the current provided that the duty cycle is under control. In my circuit I need to do balancing between batteries too. So I cannot escape of bootstrap. And my voltage is high. each battery pack is 2x3.7 volt and there are four of them. So could you give solution for bootstrapping?

Comment: Also, could you explain how P-Channel Mosfet should be bootstrapped in my case?

Comment: What is your opinion about level-shifter on the button of page 5 of [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon+-+Application+Note+-+Power+MOSFETs+-+OptiMOS+P-channel.pdf?fileId=db3a304341e0aed001420380cc13101b) article?

Comment: "it has an inductor which limits the current provided that the duty cycle is under control" NO this is wrong. You are not monitoring the current so you cannot know how to control the duty cycle to keep the current in check. You focus on details (how to control the gate) yet your whole system has serious issues.
There are ways to control an NMOS with bootstrapping, it involves some capacitors and some diodes. But that will not be a good solution because it is not enough to switch the NMOS properly.

Comment: That levelshifter solution should work provided you can find an appropriate levelshifter. But note that the circuit with the PMOS is much easier, only a small MOSFET and some resistors needed.
Oh ans since you're not planning on doing proper current limiting, please add a fuse to prevent fires, thanks ;-)

Comment: Sure, I'll put fuse. If you have any suggestion for protection, I am very happy to hear that too. BTW, could you draw/link to schematic of any P-channel configuration of Buck convertor? I hope you are not meaning that I put the load on high side.

Comment: Sorry, too lazy to make a drawing ;-) but this is what I mean: http://bbs.21dianyuan.com/158934.html  the first picture. You could leave D2 out if you wish.
I have one BIG question, what controls the dutycycle of the PWM signal driving switch ? How will you prevent your inductor from saturating (note that a saturated inductor behaves as a piece of wire !)

Comment: Thx, doesnt Vgs=-20V damage the transistor?

Comment: That depends on the transistor: look at the datasheet.
If 20 V is too much: choose a different transistor  or  use resistors to adjust the voltage.

Comment: Please update the P-Channel design in the Answer. Thanks

Comment: BTW, any way to turn off the transistor by default. What if a stupid person keeps his finger on the reset button of the microcontroller?

Comment: The fuse will just blow, that is inherent of the design you chose ! I recommended some current limiting / current feedback.

Comment: I have no idea about any limiting / current feedback. Could you suggest me any design?

Comment: No because that will be recipe for failure. Designing a proper switched mode converter (I assume that is what you're trying to build) takes intricate knowledge. You would be far better of using some standard module.
I doubt if you even can explain properly why you chose this circuit in the first place and what you want to achieve with it. Just building "something" but having no clue why and how is a recipe for disaster. It has nothing to do with proper engineering.